# ActiveRecord Integer Column won't accept some Integer assignments

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nokogiri, rails-activerecord

I'm seeing some genuinely bizarre behavior w/ ActiveRecord as it relates to assignment.  I have an ActiveRecord model named **Venue** that includes the measurements of the Venue, all integers less than 1K. We add Venues via an XML feed. On the model itself, I have a `Venue.from_xml_feed` method takes the XML, parses, and creates Venues.

The problem comes from the measurements.  Using `Nokogiri`, I'm parsing out the measurements like so:

```
   elems = xml.xpath("//*[@id]")
   elems.each do |node|
      distance = node.css("distances")
      rs = distance.attr("rs")
      // get the rest of the sides
      # using new instead of create to print right_side, behavior is the same
      venue = Venue.new right_side: rs # etc
      venue.save
      puts venue.right_side
   end
```

The problem is that `venue.right_side` **ALWAYS** evaluates to `nil`, even though `distance.attr("rs")` contains a legal value, say 400. So this code:

```
rs = distance.attr("rs")
puts rs
Venue.new right_side: rs
```

Will print `400`, then save rs as nil.  If I try any type of Type Conversions, like so:

```
content = distance.attr("rs").content
str     = content.to_s
int     = Integer(str)
puts "Is int and Integer? #{int.is_a? Integer}"
Venue.new right_side: int
```

It will print `Is int an Integer? true`, then again save again save `Venue.right_side` as `nil`.

However, if I just explicitly create a random integer like so:

```
int = 400
Venue.new right_side: int
```

It will save `Venue.right_side` as `400`.  Can anyone tell me what's going on with this?

Answer (score 0):

Well, you failed to include the prerequisite sample XML to confirm this, so you get a fairly generic answer.

In your code you're using:

```
distance = node.css("distances")
rs = distance.attr("rs")
```

`css` doesn't return what you think it does. It returns a NodeSet, which is similar to an Array. When you try to use `attr` on a NodeSet, you're going to *set* the value, not retrieve it. From the documentation:

```
#attr(key, value = nil, &blk) ⇒ Object (also: #set, #attribute)
```

> Set the attribute key to value or the return value of blk on all Node objects in the NodeSet.

Because you're not using a value, the resulting action is to remove the attribute from the tag, which will then return nil and Ruby will assign nil to `rs`.

If you want to get the attribute of a node, you need to point to the node itself, so use `at`, or `at_css`, either of which returns a Node. Once you have the node, you can use `attribute` to retrieve the value, or use the `[]` shortcut similar to this untested code:

```
rs = node.at('distances')['rs']
```

Again though, because you didn't supply XML it's not possible to tell what else you might be trying to do, or whether this code is entirely accurate.